# Rendering openGL texture: Class function causes rendering to fail

Tags: c++, class, opengl, rendering, sdl

I am working on a menu system that would allow me to apply a 'parent' to an object.  I have a `CLabel` class that renders fonts.  I have a `CEditBox` class that has a pointer to the base `CControl` class that they are all a part of.  I then declare a pointer to a `CControl` object and point it at a `CLabel` in the constructor of a `CEditBox`.

As far as I can tell, this is all set up right.  Why do I say that?  This function:

```
void CControl::RenderChildren() {
    for( int i = 0; i < Children.size(); i++ ) {


        //Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X); //offset child _X with parent's _X
        //Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()+_Y); //offset child _Y with parent's _Y

        Children[i]->OnRender();
    }
}
```

Will render the editbox, it will render the label with the labels offset (_X,_Y they are members of `CControl`).  Since they are at 0,0 it renders the text in the top left corner.

Now, if I un-comment the two lines and use the following function, the text doesn't render.

```
void CControl::RenderChildren() {
    for( int i = 0; i < Children.size(); i++ ) {


        Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X); //offset child _X with parent's _X
        Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()+_Y); //offset child _Y with parent's _Y

        Children[i]->OnRender();
    }
}
```

I have used `exit(variable)` calls to test specifically the values and can tell you several things.  _X and _Y are being set right for the child.  The Parent renders in the desired location so it's not affecting the parent's _X,_Y values.

Next, let's look at the functions I call:

```
void CControl::X(int x) {                                           
    //      Set Component's X coordinate
    _X = x;
    //if(Pappy != NULL) { 
    //  _X = _X + Pappy->X(); 
    //}
}

void CControl::Y(int y) {                                           
    //      Set Component's Y coordinate
    _Y = y;
    //if(Pappy != NULL) {
    //  _Y = _Y + Pappy->Y();
    //}
}
```

Don't mind the commented out lines, those were because I was going to check to see if it was a child of something and modify the offsets in the _X and _Y functions, but realized that it's probably more efficient to not worry about it and only apply offsets when rendering children (Hence my original function above).  Simply put, these functions just set the passed integer to the current offset.

Then the read version of the functions:

```
int CControl::X() {                                             
    //      Get Component's X coordinate
    //if(Pappy != NULL) return _X - Pappy->X();
    return _X;
}

int CControl::Y() {                                             
    //      Get Component's Y coordinate
    //if(Pappy != NULL) return _Y - Pappy->Y();
    return _Y;
}
```

Also just returning the values,  I cannot figure out how the two lines

```
    Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X); //offset child _X with parent's _X
    Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()+_Y); //offset child _Y with parent's _Y
```

Are causing the rendering to fail.

Looking into my `CLabel::OnRender()` function, I also cannot detect the problem.

```
void CLabel::OnRender() {

    if(Visible) {
        SDL_Surface* Surf_Text; 
        Surf_Text = Font.BlendedUTF8Surface();
        Text_Font.OnLoad(Surf_Text);
        Text_Font.RenderQuad(_X,_Y);
        SDL_FreeSurface(Surf_Text);
    }
}
```

I know the code is entering here.  I have used `exit(variable)` inside the `if` statement.  I have tested `Surf_Text->w` and `Surf_Text->h` and know that text is rendering because there is no difference in the SDL_Surface values with or without the offset lines and it renders in one occasion but not the other.  Furthermore, I tested _X and _Y in this function just to verify they are indeed rendering in the proper place.  They are.

That would imply that maybe something is wrong in the render order, but in this function if I replace `Text_Font.RenderQuad(_X,_Y);` with `Text_Font.RenderQuad(_X+dX,_Y+dY);` where dX and dY are just the integer values that it should be after applying the parent offset, the text renders just fine.  So everything I can think of, I have tested.  I cannot figure out why these two offset lines kill the rendering.

```
    Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X); //offset child _X with parent's _X
    Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()+_Y); //offset child _Y with parent's _Y
```

## [SOLVED]

Yep.  Went and thought about it for a minute.

Frame 1)

```
Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X) // will be 100 and exit correctly.
```

frame 2)

```
Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X) // will be 200 if I don't add the exit
```

etc...

Made my function:

```
void CControl::RenderChildren() {
    for( int i = 0; i < Children.size(); i++ ) {


        Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X); //offset child _X with parent's _X
        Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()+_Y); //offset child _Y with parent's _Y

        Children[i]->OnRender();

        Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()-_X);
        Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()-_Y);
    }
}
```

Renders perfectly.  Hope I didn't waste anyone's time.

## [SOLUTION 2]

Reading the selected answer, I chose to rewrite the functions to apply offsets during rendering.  I just calculate offsets before rendering the children as shown below:

```
void CControl::RenderChildren() {
    for( int i = 0; i < Children.size(); i++ ) {

        int xOff, yOff;
        xOff = yOff = 0;                                //Initialize offsets

        CControl * Kin = this;                          //Pointer to current parent
        while( Kin != NULL ) {                          //Until there is no more parent container repeat
            xOff = Kin->X() + xOff;                     //Add X of Parent to the current X offset total.
            yOff = Kin->Y() + yOff;                     //Add Y of Parent to the current Y offset total.
            Kin = Kin->GetParent();                     //Get next parent.  
        }

        Children[i]->OnRender(xOff,yOff);               //Render based on parental induced offset location

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did see your mistake within one second. So you didn't waste anyone's time (except your own ;) ). Anyway doing it like this:

> ```
> void CControl::RenderChildren() {
>     for( int i = 0; i < Children.size(); i++ ) {
>
>
>         Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()+_X); //offset child _X with parent's _X
>         Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()+_Y); //offset child _Y with parent's _Y
>
>         Children[i]->OnRender();
>
>         Children[i]->X(Children[i]->X()-_X);
>         Children[i]->Y(Children[i]->Y()-_Y);
>     }
> }
> ```

is not optimal. In your case you're using integers where you're experiencing any problems. *But say at one point you decide to use floats*:

The problem is, that every operation happening on floating point numbers creates round off error. Doing it iteratively (like in your case) may either converge the number at a stable point, or it may ever so slightly diverge. As a general rule you should minimize the operations through which single floating point number "flows". Mathematically your preamble and postamble may look like exacts inverses of each other. Practically on a computer with limited precision they're not.

*To make a long story short:*

You should slightly change `CControl::OnRender` to take the offset as parameters, so that it applies the offset addition in-situ when rendering. Don't mind the extra work. If it's really a problem use a profiler to identify the true bottleneck. Don't design your interfaces with certain "ideas" about performance in mind. Premature optimization is that, and it's no good.

---

**BTW: On StackOverflow the canonical way to mark self solved problems is to write your own solution into an answer to your own question and then mark that as accepted.**

Comment: Hi Datenwolf.  Thanks for the response.  Quickly, thanks for the note on how to answer my own question.  I'm still relatively new here.

You bring up an awesome point.  So essentially, because of rounding, each cycle could end up with a net change in _X or _Y so the component would eventually slide off the screen (or in the event of some cyclic rounding issue, oscillate a little on screen.)

Canonically speaking, are pixels usually handled as floats?  It seems int would be the better choice for the pixel coordinate (less memory), but I have very little formal training in graphics.

Comment: Well, I guess in terms of memory they are the same but I always though the calculation cost was less for integers.

Comment: @Chemistpp: Pixels are usually just elements in a linearily addressed portion of memory (with the occasional alignment gap in between, depending on window size and pixel format). So pixel addresses always are integers. However pixels themself may be floating point values. As for the behavior of float coordinates: Yes they may oscillate or slowly slide off viewport.

Comment: Ok, fixed my algorithm.  Should work better under most circumstances I guess.